# Meaning of Bias with zero inputs in Perception at ANNs

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm student in a graduate computer science program. Yesterday we had a lecture about neural networks. 
I think I understood the specific parts of a perceptron in neural networks with one exception. I already made my research about the bias in an perceptron- but still I didn't got it. 
So far I know that, with the bias I can manipulate the sum over the inputs with there weights in a perception to evaluate that the sum minus a specific bias is bigger than the activation function threshold - if the function should fire (Sigmoid).
But on the presentation slides from my professor he mentioned something like this:

> The bias is added to the perceptron to avoid issues where all inputs
>   could be equal to zero - no multiplicative weight would have an effect

I can't figure out whats the meaning behind this sentence and why is it important, that sum over all weighted inputs can't be equal to zero ?. If all inputs are equal to zero, there should be no impact on the next perceptions in the next hidden layer, right? Furthermore this perception is a static value for backpropagation and has no influence on changing this weights at the perception.
Or am I wrong?

Has anyone a solution for that?
thanks in advance

Comment: imagine Nor function. With input [0, 0],the output is 1. You can't do that without a bias.

Comment: So the bias should guarantee that my function is always running to compute e.g. nor(0,0) ? so my bias should always be bigger than my threshold?

Comment: I like @Eryl Kenner answer, with the statement 'bias is an offset'. Bias is there to add some unlinearity in your output. and this bias is not 'static', because it is attached to a weight like others neurons, so it can be modified with backpropagation !
Think of a linear function like 2x. You can't get the ouput 1 with the input 0. If you add a bias terme, 2x+1, you can get the output 1 with input 0. And as the bias can be modified, you can get the output -2 with your input 1 !! (with the function 2x-4 !! bias = -4)

Answer (score 0):

## Bias

A bias is essentially an **offset.**

Imagine the simple case of a single perceptron, with a relationship between the input and the output, say:

**y = 2x + 3**

Without the bias term, the perceptron could match the slope (often called the weight) of **"2"**, meaning it could learn:

**y = 2x**

but it could not match the **"+ 3"** part.

Although this is a simple example, this logic scales to neural networks in general. The neural network can capture nonlinear functions, but often it needs an offset to do so.

### What you asked

What your professor said is another good example of why an offset would be needed. Imagine all the inputs to a perceptron are 0. A perceptron's output is the sum of each of the inputs multiplied by a weight. This means that each weight is being multiplied by 0, then added together. Therefore, the result will always be 0.

With a bias, however, the output could still retain a value.

Comment: but why is it important that my output retains at at value?

Comment: unless, you can't optimize to every functions. Think of the NOR gate example I gave you.

Comment: @Leon if you are attempting to train your network to approximate some function or a data set, a constant output of 0 will not be helpful. In the professor's example, the output is always locked to zero, meaning you have essentially **lost control** of the output of the network. No amount of change in the weights can **ever** produce a different output, meaning you can never train your network.